# Remove custom field or workflow alert via ant migration tool

Tags: metadata, ant

Is it possible to remove workflow alerts or custom fields via ant migration tool?
If yes: how do I do that?

```
<types>
    <members>Convention_Approved_Email_Send</members>
    <name>WorkflowAlert</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and [there is documentation that covers what you need to do](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm).

The gist of the documentation is that you'll need to create a `destuctiveChanges.xml` file that lists all of the metadata that you want to delete.

The format of `destructiveChanges.xml` is the same as `package.xml`, just that no wildcards are allowed.

If you're only deleting metadata, in your build.xml file, you won't need to `<sf:retrieve>`, just `<sf:deploy>`, pointing the `deployRoot` to the directory that contains your `destructiveChanges.xml` file.

An 'empty' `package.xml` in the same directory is also required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <version>38.0</version>
    </Package>
```

If you're adding and deleting at the same time, your `package.xml` will need to specify all the metadata that you want to add (just like normal), and your build target will need to `<sf:retrieve>` (just like normal).

Comment: yes I found that to but it doesn't remove my workflow alerts. I have updated my question with the part that I added. Feel free to correct it.

Comment: Are you able to deploy a new workflow email alert using the `WorkflowAlert` metadata type? If all else fails, I suppose you could delete the entire workflow rule (and re-deploy it from an environment where the target `WorkflowAlert` has been deleted). I'm not sure if you'd need to set `purgeOnDelete` or not.